# Pandas dataframe drop columns with no header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, nan

What's the most pythonic place to drop the columns in a dataframe where the header row is NaN?  Preferably inplace.

There may or may not be data in the column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,np.NaN], 'col2': [4,5,6], np.NaN: [7,np.NaN,9]})
df.dropna(axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

Doesn't do it as it looks at the data in the column.

Wanted output

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,np.NaN], 'col2': [4,5,6]})
```

Thanks in advance for the replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Index.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.dropna.html):

```
df = df[df.columns.dropna()]

print(df)

   col1  col2
0   1.0     4
1   2.0     5
2   NaN     6
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply try this

```
df.drop(np.nan, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

However, if 'no headers' includes `None`, then **jpp**'s answer will work perfectly at one shot. 
Even, in case you have more than one `np.nan` headers, I don't know how to make `df.drop` works.

Comment: why passing as  a list?

Comment: habit :D. doesn't have to. thanks for making perfect!